# Como faço para rodar um vídeo dentro do JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Quero abrir uma tela e nela conter tipo um player pra rodar o vídeo que esteja anexado ao projeto!

Comment: Eu diria para você fazer com JavaFX que possui várias APIs de manipulação de mídia.

Comment: Só acrescentando: É possível integrar o JavaFX dentro de uma aplicação Swing. Assim você pode utilizar o que já conhece do pacote Swing e pesquisar somente como inserir um componente de mídia dentro do `JFrame`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: O que você tentou?

Answer (score 3):

A idéia de usar JavaFX é interessante. Em JavaFX, rodar um vídeo seria assim:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TocandoVideo extends Application {

    private String VIDEO_URL = getClass().getResource(
            "/video/creativecommons.mp4").toString();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage palco) throws Exception {
        Media media = new Media(VIDEO_URL); // 1
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media); // 2
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer); // 3

        StackPane raiz = new StackPane();
        raiz.getChildren().add(mediaView); // 4
        Scene cena = new Scene(raiz, 600, 400);
        palco.setTitle("Tocando Video em JavaFX");
        palco.setScene(cena);
        palco.show();

        mediaPlayer.play(); // 4
    }
}
```

Como em [Tocando Vídeo em JavaFX](http://aprendendo-javafx.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/tocando-audio-e-video.html) e chamar a classe FX dentro do Swing assim:

```
package dustin.examples;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Simple class demonstrating interoperability between Swing and JavaFX. This
 * class is adapted from the example provided in the Javadoc documentation for
 * {@code javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel}.
 */
public class SwingJavaFxInteroperabilityDemo
{
    private static void initAndShowGUI()
    {
        // This method is invoked on Swing thread
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaFX / Swing Integrated");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel)
    {
        // This method is invoked on JavaFX thread
        final Scene scene = TextIntegrationSceneCreator.createTextScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Como em [Integrando JavaFX e Swing](http://java.dzone.com/articles/integrating-javafx-20-swing).

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é usar mesmo Java, com `swing` recomendo usar a biblioteca `xuggler` http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler , existe vários exemplos implementados com essa biblioteca.

*necessário 2 bibliotecas*

1. Xuggler download(onde eu fiz o download link):http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/
2. Logger usei esta slf4j-1.7.7.zip download: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Exemplo de código fornecido pelo site:

```
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoResampler;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Utils;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.VideoImage;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

/**
 * Takes a media container, finds the first video stream,
 * decodes that stream, and then plays the audio and video.
 *
 * This code does a VERY coarse job of matching time-stamps, and thus
 * the audio and video will float in and out of slight sync.  Getting
 * time-stamps syncing-up with audio is very system dependent and left
 * as an exercise for the reader.
 * 
 * @author aclarke
 *
 */
public class DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo
{

  /**
   * The audio line we'll output sound to; it'll be the default audio device on your system if available
   */
  private static SourceDataLine mLine;

  /**
   * The window we'll draw the video on.
   * 
   */
  private static VideoImage mScreen = null;

  private static long mSystemVideoClockStartTime;

  private static long mFirstVideoTimestampInStream;

  /**
   * Takes a media container (file) as the first argument, opens it,
   * plays audio as quickly as it can, and opens up a Swing window and displays
   * video frames with <i>roughly</i> the right timing.
   *  
   * @param args Must contain one string which represents a filename
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {


// _________alteração do original_________
//    if (args.length <= 0)
//      throw new IllegalArgumentException("must pass in a filename as the first argument");

 //Caminho do video para reproduzir

    String filename = "C:\\Wildlife.wmv";

    // Let's make sure that we can actually convert video pixel formats.
    if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION))
      throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for this demo to work");

    // Create a Xuggler container object
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();

    // Open up the container
    if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);

    // query how many streams the call to open found
    int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

    // and iterate through the streams to find the first audio stream
    int videoStreamId = -1;
    IStreamCoder videoCoder = null;
    int audioStreamId = -1;
    IStreamCoder audioCoder = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
      // Find the stream object
      IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
      // Get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
      IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

      if (videoStreamId == -1 && coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
      {
        videoStreamId = i;
        videoCoder = coder;
      }
      else if (audioStreamId == -1 && coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
      {
        audioStreamId = i;
        audioCoder = coder;
      }
    }
    if (videoStreamId == -1 && audioStreamId == -1)
      throw new RuntimeException("could not find audio or video stream in container: "+filename);

    /*
     * Check if we have a video stream in this file.  If so let's open up our decoder so it can
     * do work.
     */
    IVideoResampler resampler = null;
    if (videoCoder != null)
    {
      if(videoCoder.open() < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: "+filename);

      if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24)
      {
        // if this stream is not in BGR24, we're going to need to
        // convert it.  The VideoResampler does that for us.
        resampler = IVideoResampler.make(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24,
            videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder.getPixelType());
        if (resampler == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("could not create color space resampler for: " + filename);
      }
      /*
       * And once we have that, we draw a window on screen
       */
      openJavaVideo();
    }

    if (audioCoder != null)
    {
      if (audioCoder.open() < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: "+filename);

      /*
       * And once we have that, we ask the Java Sound System to get itself ready.
       */
      try
      {
        openJavaSound(audioCoder);
      }
      catch (LineUnavailableException ex)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("unable to open sound device on your system when playing back container: "+filename);
      }
    }


    /*
     * Now, we start walking through the container looking at each packet.
     */
    IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
    mFirstVideoTimestampInStream = Global.NO_PTS;
    mSystemVideoClockStartTime = 0;
    while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0)
    {
      /*
       * Now we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to our video stream
       */
      if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId)
      {
        /*
         * We allocate a new picture to get the data out of Xuggler
         */
        IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(),
            videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());

        /*
         * Now, we decode the video, checking for any errors.
         * 
         */
        int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, 0);
        if (bytesDecoded < 0)
          throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);

        /*
         * Some decoders will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
         * a full video picture yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
         * got a complete picture from the decoder
         */
        if (picture.isComplete())
        {
          IVideoPicture newPic = picture;
          /*
           * If the resampler is not null, that means we didn't get the video in BGR24 format and
           * need to convert it into BGR24 format.
           */
          if (resampler != null)
          {
            // we must resample
            newPic = IVideoPicture.make(resampler.getOutputPixelFormat(), picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
            if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0)
              throw new RuntimeException("could not resample video from: " + filename);
          }
          if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24)
            throw new RuntimeException("could not decode video as BGR 24 bit data in: " + filename);

          long delay = millisecondsUntilTimeToDisplay(newPic);
          // if there is no audio stream; go ahead and hold up the main thread.  We'll end
          // up caching fewer video pictures in memory that way.
          try
          {
            if (delay > 0)
              Thread.sleep(delay);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            return;
          }

          // And finally, convert the picture to an image and display it

          mScreen.setImage(Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic));
        }
      }
      else if (packet.getStreamIndex() == audioStreamId)
      {
        /*
         * We allocate a set of samples with the same number of channels as the
         * coder tells us is in this buffer.
         * 
         * We also pass in a buffer size (1024 in our example), although Xuggler
         * will probably allocate more space than just the 1024 (it's not important why).
         */
        IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(1024, audioCoder.getChannels());

        /*
         * A packet can actually contain multiple sets of samples (or frames of samples
         * in audio-decoding speak).  So, we may need to call decode audio multiple
         * times at different offsets in the packet's data.  We capture that here.
         */
        int offset = 0;

        /*
         * Keep going until we've processed all data
         */
        while(offset < packet.getSize())
        {
          int bytesDecoded = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, packet, offset);
          if (bytesDecoded < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);
          offset += bytesDecoded;
          /*
           * Some decoder will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
           * a full set of samples yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
           * got a complete set of samples from the decoder
           */
          if (samples.isComplete())
          {
            // note: this call will block if Java's sound buffers fill up, and we're
            // okay with that.  That's why we have the video "sleeping" occur
            // on another thread.
            playJavaSound(samples);
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        /*
         * This packet isn't part of our video stream, so we just silently drop it.
         */
        do {} while(false);
      }

    }
    /*
     * Technically since we're exiting anyway, these will be cleaned up by 
     * the garbage collector... but because we're nice people and want
     * to be invited places for Christmas, we're going to show how to clean up.
     */
    if (videoCoder != null)
    {
      videoCoder.close();
      videoCoder = null;
    }
    if (audioCoder != null)
    {
      audioCoder.close();
      audioCoder = null;
    }
    if (container !=null)
    {
      container.close();
      container = null;
    }
    closeJavaSound();
    closeJavaVideo();
  }

  private static long millisecondsUntilTimeToDisplay(IVideoPicture picture)
  {
    /**
     * We could just display the images as quickly as we decode them, but it turns
     * out we can decode a lot faster than you think.
     * 
     * So instead, the following code does a poor-man's version of trying to
     * match up the frame-rate requested for each IVideoPicture with the system
     * clock time on your computer.
     * 
     * Remember that all Xuggler IAudioSamples and IVideoPicture objects always
     * give timestamps in Microseconds, relative to the first decoded item.  If
     * instead you used the packet timestamps, they can be in different units depending
     * on your IContainer, and IStream and things can get hairy quickly.
     */
    long millisecondsToSleep = 0;
    if (mFirstVideoTimestampInStream == Global.NO_PTS)
    {
      // This is our first time through
      mFirstVideoTimestampInStream = picture.getTimeStamp();
      // get the starting clock time so we can hold up frames
      // until the right time.
      mSystemVideoClockStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      millisecondsToSleep = 0;
    } else {
      long systemClockCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo = systemClockCurrentTime - mSystemVideoClockStartTime;
      // compute how long for this frame since the first frame in the stream.
      // remember that IVideoPicture and IAudioSamples timestamps are always in MICROSECONDS,
      // so we divide by 1000 to get milliseconds.
      long millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo = (picture.getTimeStamp() - mFirstVideoTimestampInStream)/1000;
      final long millisecondsTolerance = 50; // and we give ourselfs 50 ms of tolerance
      millisecondsToSleep = (millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo -
          (millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo+millisecondsTolerance));
    }
    return millisecondsToSleep;
  }

  /**
   * Opens a Swing window on screen.
   */
  private static void openJavaVideo()
  {
    mScreen = new VideoImage();
  }

  /**
   * Forces the swing thread to terminate; I'm sure there is a right
   * way to do this in swing, but this works too.
   */
  private static void closeJavaVideo()
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }

  private static void openJavaSound(IStreamCoder aAudioCoder) throws LineUnavailableException
  {
    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(aAudioCoder.getSampleRate(),
        (int)IAudioSamples.findSampleBitDepth(aAudioCoder.getSampleFormat()),
        aAudioCoder.getChannels(),
        true, /* xuggler defaults to signed 16 bit samples */
        false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
    mLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    /**
     * if that succeeded, try opening the line.
     */
    mLine.open(audioFormat);
    /**
     * And if that succeed, start the line.
     */
    mLine.start();


  }

  private static void playJavaSound(IAudioSamples aSamples)
  {
    /**
     * We're just going to dump all the samples into the line.
     */
    byte[] rawBytes = aSamples.getData().getByteArray(0, aSamples.getSize());
    mLine.write(rawBytes, 0, aSamples.getSize());
  }

  private static void closeJavaSound()
  {
    if (mLine != null)
    {
      /*
       * Wait for the line to finish playing
       */
      mLine.drain();
      /*
       * Close the line.
       */
      mLine.close();
      mLine=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Link deste código: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo.java